# How can I check if a server supports xmpp or not?

Tags: xmpp

Is there anyway in which I can check if a server supports XMPP protocol or not?

I am very new to XMPP, and I am dealing with a shared server. I am supposed to use XMPP to create a chatting system. But as I read about XMPP, I am supposed to install openfire and I have no access to the server itself.

So I want to check if the server supports xmpp or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the XMPP RFC which includes recommended port numbers:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#section-15.9

So you could try connecting to port 5222 on a server (with a proper XMPP client, a plain socket in C, the telnet program, or whatever).  Note also that port 5223 is used by some XMPP servers for SSL/TLS (as noted in appendix D.1. of the RFC).